# I want to filter my data based on datetime

Tags: c#

I have in my DB a datetime column formatted as ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
When I try to fetch data based on a selected time nothing displays. but if I format the date as ("dd/MM/yyyy"). It works perfect

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from workdays where date " + " between @fromdate and @todate", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", DbType.DateTime).Value = dtpFromDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", DbType.DateTime).Value = dtpToDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Simply remove the `.ToString` parts. Datetimes are *not* strings. Converting them to strings is used to display them, not work with them.

Comment: Also, just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stringify datetime parameter in your query at all, just do:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fromdate", DbType.DateTime).Value = dtpFromDate.Value;
```

**EDIT:**

Corrected mistake highligted by @Steve in comments. `AddWithValue` second parameter is actual value to be used for parameter, not type.

**EDIT 2:**

Using `Add` is recommended though as highlighted by @AndrewMorton

Comment: The second parameter in AddWithValue is not the Type but the Value. Your code is correct for Add instead

Comment: @NikitaChayka The mistake was to use AddWithValue instead of Add. The former often works, but can get things wrong sometimes (please see my comment on the question).

Comment: @AndrewMorton agree

Comment: To all, I appreciate your swift response to assisting me

Comment: When I tried this cmd.Parameters.Add("@fromdate", DbType.DateTime).Value = dtpFromDate.Value;. It is highlighted as a warning. but filter still fails after trying

Comment: @IshmaelMensah are you sure then that the dtpFromDate.Value value exists in database? I think that in the database you don't have records with same  hours or minutes or seconds, but with the same day (that's why dd/MM/yyyy worked)

Comment: Are you sure @IshmaelMensah that your _date_ column in the database is of type Date or DateTime?

Comment: @Steve: this '2020-10-12 13:51:06.000' was copied from the db. Does the format (eg. dd/MM/yyyy in the designer property) have any effect.

Comment: @NikitaChayka I thought as much, but how would I select the time from the dtpFromDate object?

Comment: @IshmaelMensah debug the application

Comment: @IshmaelMensah the format used to display the date is irrelevant. I want to know the database type that you can see looking at the table structure

Comment: @Steve datatype for date column is (datetime) pls